# Trying to create stored procedure in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a procedure in Oracle. I want to be able to call on the procedure with a variable input and have a statement read. I am in the process of learning Oracle SQL, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

This is my code:

```
create or replace procedure gradeCheck(grade char(1))

Begin 
  Case
    When grade = 'A' then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Great Work')
    else DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not great work')
  end case;
end gradeCheck;
/

Begin 
  gradeCheck(A);
end;
/
```

I want the input to be 'A' (the grade assignment) and to get the text output. I am getting a message that the `GRADECHECK` procedure is being compiled. But it won't let me call it with an input.

Comment: Depending on your client it's probably telling you that the procedure has been compiled *with errors*. In SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer and SQLcl you can do `show errors` after that message to see the problems it found. Or you can query the `user_errors` view, filtering by name (uppercase as it isn't a quoted identifier) if there are other invalid objects. [This is what your code produces](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4c4d60908d0fd9e67cd7242ae676d98). Then you still have to understand the errors, of course, which isn't always easy...

Comment: Since your are new to this, a side observation about coding style and object naming.  In oracle, if you do _not_ double quote object names when you create them, they are case INsenstive.  This is a good thing. It means you can refer to your procedure as 'gradeCheck', or 'GradeCheck', or GrAdEcHeCk.  But it is stored in the data dictionary in all caps - GRADECHECK.  So, in the oracle world, the common practice to get the read-ability of CamelCase (common in the mssql world) is to use underscores instead:  grade_check.   (continued ....)

Comment: (....continueing)  If you think you want the object name to be truely mix-case (in the dictionary) then you have to create it with double quotes: "gradeCheck".  But this will forever make it case-SENsitive, an all future references will have to be also enclosed in double-quotes and in the exact case in which it was created.  This can thus lead to a lot of 'object not found' errors, and so is considered to be poor practice in the oracle world.

Comment: Most important point, when it says compiled with errors you should ask for the errors - use the `show errors` statement to do this. This will tell you what the compilation errors are and where to find them, sometimes the compilation error message can get a bit confusing but it is the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Your issues

- You are missing a word `is` in the `create or replace` statement
- If the input variable is string ( char ) then you have to enclose in quotes the value when you call the procedure.
- Use `varchar2` instead of `char`, although it is not mandatory.
- `;` must be at the end of `dbms_output`
- If you run it with `sqlplus`, use `set serveroutput on` to enable the output, that you can see the message.

Then

```
create or replace procedure gradeCheck(grade in varchar2)
is
Begin 
  case when grade = 'A' 
   then 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Great Work');
   else 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not great work');
  end case;
end gradeCheck;
/

set serveroutput on 
Begin 
  gradeCheck('A');
end;
/
```

Test Case

```
SQL> l
  1   create or replace procedure gradeCheck(grade in varchar2)
  2   is
  3   Begin
  4     case
  5       when grade = 'A' then
  6         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Great Work');
  7       else
  8         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not great work');
  9     end case;
 10*  end gradeCheck;
SQL> /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2  gradeCheck('A');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> r
  1  begin
  2  gradeCheck('A');
  3* end;
Great Work

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

- You want use `IF` not `CASE`
- You are missing the `IS` keyword before `BEGIN`
- You need to terminate statements with `;`
- The `CHAR` data type does not have a length in the signature.

Like this:

```sql
create procedure gradeCheck(
  grade CHAR
)
IS
BEGIN
  IF grade = 'A' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Great Work');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not great work');
  END IF;
END gradeCheck;
/
```

Then you need to use quotes around the string:

```
Begin
  gradeCheck('A');
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9fbf131a65d0effb77d8d1d3da25709b)*

Comment: Thank you! Always seems to be small changes. For the record, I was specifically trying to use 'case' as opposed to 'if' to understand that logical structure better. I want to be able to use both though.